# Encrypted external disk, with no need to enter password each time

Tags: gratis, linux, encryption, hard-disk

There are many solutions to encrypt an external disk. Unfortunately, they require me to type my long password every time I plug the disk, which is several times per day.

My special need: I don't want to enter a password each time I connect the disk

After initial setup, I would use it this way:

1. Plug the disk to my Linux via USB.
2. Linux somehow recognizes the disk, gets some key stored in my Linux home, use it to mount the disk. Within a few seconds, without asking me for anything.
3. I can use the disk normally.

I am on Ubuntu, if that matters. Bonus if the password can be saved to a file, so that my disk content does not become unreadable forever if my PC is stolen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LUKS](https://guardianproject.info/code/luks/) encryption for your external hard drive.

Anytime you plug in the drive, Ubuntu automonts the drive and directly asks for the password. Showing you an option when to forget it:

- immediately
- at the end of the session
- never

--> looks like this:

[image: unlock]
<sup>Unlock dialog (source: [gnu-designs.com](http://blog.gnu-designs.com/solved-howto-mount-an-external-encrypted-luks-volume-under-linux/); click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Strange I don't remember seeing that option (I don't have any encrypted disk to check right now). Would you have a screenshot showing that popup? That would be a wonderfully simple solution, as I believe Ubuntu uses LUKS+ext4 by default for external encrypted disks :-)

Comment: I'm at work, having my external hard drive at home, but it looks like [**this**](http://blog.gnu-designs.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/ecryptfs-LUKS-dialog.png) [via](http://blog.gnu-designs.com/solved-howto-mount-an-external-encrypted-luks-volume-under-linux/)

Comment: Same image I had found, but sonehow the website times out for me, and the name "gnu-designs.com" made me think it might be only mockups...

Comment: I use it exactly that way and I can confirm that it works just perfect.

Comment: What it the use of the encryption here if the password is never forgotten? Why to encrypt at all in this situation?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny The password is only saved on your computer in your personal (encrypted) keychain. Plug in the HDD anywhere else (other computer or other account@same computer) requires entering the key again.

Comment: @Rovo Why to plug the drive anywhere else if you just can turn the PC on, copy everything you want to another drive or flash chip? I understand, that this is for convenience, but this is not a good security to never ask for a password, you know.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny: First you need physical access to that computer, then you need the password for the User Account. That's a two-factor authentication. That is for **most** personal use cases enough security.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny: If anyone ever gains physical access to my laptop (which I consider improbable), it is total game over already. On the opposite, I leave my external disk at random places (hotel rooms, open spaces, etc) because I don't need the data on it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TrueCrypt.  This has a "cache passwords in memory" option, that will do this for you.

This is a cross-platform solution, so you can also easily then mount the drive on Windows, etc.

If you use the pre-boot authentication to encrypt your system drive, then you can even cache that password, so you *never* have to enter the password for external drives.

[Yes, I know Truecrypt is out of support, but it still works well enough for most purposes]

Comment: Thanks! Does it mount within a few seconds, without asking me for anything? Or do I have to run something after plugging the USB cable in?

Comment: You can set it to auto-mount devices on connection.